# Highlighting specific cells on hover of a cell in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, hover

I have the following table (real table is bigger, implemented in WordPress):

```
<table id="tablepress-71" class="tablepress tablepress-id-71">
       <tr class="row-1">
         <td class="column-1"><span><a href="#">Item 1</a></span></td>
         <td class="column-2"><span><a href="#">Item 2</a></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-2">
         <td class="column-1"><span><a href="#">Item 3</a></span></td>
         <td class="column-2"><span><a href="#">Item 4</a></span></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

I need to highlight (background-color) a sub-set of cells upon hover on a specific cell.
For example, on hover over cell ***.row-1 .column-2*** I want the following cells to highlight:
***.row-1 .column-2*** and 
***.row-2 .column-2***

There are 8 cells to accept hover, each highlighting a specific group of cells on the table (no rules, just a specified list), upon hover.

Can use CSS and/or JS.

Comment: You lost me at `no rules, just a specified list`. So You have the list that you want to highlight? Or You want to highlight all cells on the same column?

Comment: Bogdan, no rules = a specified list of cells, NOT anything like "all cells in row" / "all cells in column" / "all white cells".... I must LIST the cells to be highlighted for each hovered cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this. If not can you clarify.

Add a class of active to all column2 cells:

```
$('td.row-1 .column-2').hover(function(){
    $('.column-2').toggleClass('active');
});
```

or:

Add a class of active to specific column2 cell:

```
$('.column-2').hover(function(){
    $('this').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, bklynM!
This worked for me:
$('.row-1 .column-2').hover(function(){
    $('.row-2 .column-2').addClass('active');
    $('.row-2 .column-1').addClass('active');
});

However, how do I remove the red background when hover is finished? need to revert back to original background color...

Comment: I changed the addClass to toggleClass in my answer above.  Accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Not working anymore - addClass or toggleClass.
$('.row-1 .column-2').hover(function(){
    $('.row-2 .column-2').toggleClass('active');
});
Also with the "td." in the element class name - doesn't work. What am I missing?
See here: https://jsfiddle.net/morsagmon/g4w2ttpy/3/

Comment: I tidied it up and it's working now in my fiddle. I also took out the border and bold on the hover style as it was making the cell jump and you probably don't need the weight on the css name, okay to use .active and .active span a: https://jsfiddle.net/g4w2ttpy/28/

Comment: Yesssss.Thanks!
One more question: how do I limit this JS only to the specific tablepress-71 table?

Comment: Great. All you'd have to do is add the id to the selector, like this https://jsfiddle.net/g4w2ttpy/29/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "no rules, just a specified list" you meant that each cell would have a list of other, specific cells you want highlighted when that first cell is hovered over. But that these cells would be somewhat arbitrary from a code perspective. (ie, not governed by any rules or logic).

If that assumpion is correct, and if you're open to using jquery, you could do something like the following for the javascript (assuming you have a class called "highlight" in your CSS):

```
$('.row-1 .column-2').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.row-1 .column-2').addClass('highlight');
  $('.row-2 .column-2').addClass('highlight');
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('.row-1 .column-2').removeClass('highlight');
  $('.row-2 .column-2').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

It'll be a bit wordy since you'll have to write out exactly which cells you want highlighted for every cell that's hovered over. But if there's no rules governing the behavior, that's best approach that came to my mind.

Good luck!

Here's a working example: [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGBNKZ/%22code%20pen%22)

Comment: Thanks!
You understood exactly what I need :)
The code doesn't work for me (and code pen is down). no hover effect at all.
Using jQuery.

Comment: hmmm not sure why the code pen isn't working (it's my first time posting here so maybe I did something wrong, but the link works for me), but it looks like the answer from bklynM worked for you, so that's great!